# Puppeteer: How to apply the same backgroud to the footer on a pdf page?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm creating a pdf with puppeteer and I need to add page number.
I used

```
    const pdf = await page.pdf({
        format : 'Letter',  
        displayHeaderFooter : true,
        headerTemplate : '',
        footerTemplate : `<div class='footer' style='font-size:12px; text-align:right; color:white; background:black; -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact'>
  <span class='pageNumber'></span>/<span class='totalPages'></span>
</div>`,
        margin: {top: 40, bottom: 30}, 
        printBackground: true
        });
```

but both footer and header are white. In the footer only the small area behind the page number is black but futhermore when I save the file it return white.
Even the align-right doesn't work.
I need the page number at the bottom-right of the page, how can I achieve that?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The bottom margin of 30px is not enough when I test your `options` object. I used `40px` and got the footer displayed. Alignment right would work only if the template `width` will be set to `100%`. As the result the following code ...

```
const pdf = await page.pdf({
    format : "Letter",  
    displayHeaderFooter : true,
    headerTemplate : "",
    footerTemplate : "<div class='footer' style='width: 100%; font-size:12px; text-align:right; color:white; background:black; -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact'><span class='pageNumber'></span>/<span class='totalPages'></span></div>",
    margin: {top: "40", bottom: "40"}, 
    printBackground: true
    });
```

will produce the following result ...

[image]

Comment: thanks, I'd like to have the page number like into page instead of footer but even with backgroud black still a white row under the page and a small row over.

Comment: Hello! I'm doing something like this, but with an image, I want it to be at bottom 0, that is, it is all the way to the end of the page without that white stripe that you show us in your example. Did you manage to do it?

Comment: Sorry, but I never need it, I just tried to answer the OP question. You might ask the community in a separate thread, or ask the OP if he got any further.